# The traits in Groovy change the class type compatibility?

Tags: groovy

My test code below:

```
trait Behavior {
}

class Dog {
    def greet() {
        println 'Hi, I am a dog.'
    }
}

def foo(Dog dog) {
    dog.greet()
}

def dog = new Dog() as Behavior
dog.greet()
foo(dog)
```

It gives errors as below:

```
Hi, I am a dog.
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test2.foo() is applicable for argument types: (Dog1_groovyProxy) values: [Dog1_groovyProxy@48f278eb]
Possible solutions: foo(Dog), run(), run(), any(), find(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test2.foo() is applicable for argument types: (Dog1_groovyProxy) values: [Dog1_groovyProxy@48f278eb]
Possible solutions: foo(Dog), run(), run(), any(), find(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
    at test2.run(test2.groovy:18)
```

Why does the trait change the class type of 'dog'? When it implements the trait 'Behavior', it won't be an instance of class Dog? Calling 'foo' method gives errors.

Trait changes class type compatibility unlike 'implement'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as` here changes the instance type to a `Behavior`, as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-traits.html#_implementing_a_trait_at_runtime)

> When coercing an object to a trait, the result of the operation is not the same instance. It is guaranteed that the coerced object will implement both the trait and the interfaces that the original object implements, but the result will not be an instance of the original class.